# Define features for Cargo profiles in Cargo.toml

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm using Cargo Features (https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) to specify conditional compilation options. Is there a way to enable a set of these features for a given Cargo profile (https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html)?

For example, something like this (which does not seem to work):

```
[features]
foo = []

[profile.test]
features = ["foo"]
```

So that I don't have to write `cargo test --features "foo"` but will instead just write `cargo test`.

Comment: I had the same issue once and I ended up writing a shell script with `cargo test --all-features ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't any option which can help in specifying automatic features for profiles.

You can make aliases in your shell for running those repeated commands or better yet, use [Just](https://github.com/casey/just) which is an amazing command runner written in Rust.