# does profile-rustflags allow setting features based on profile?

Tags: rust-cargo

my understanding (e.g. see this question [Define features for Cargo profiles in Cargo.toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61815549/define-features-for-cargo-profiles-in-cargo-toml)), is that it's not possible to set features based on cargo profile.

However there is an unstable cargo implementation for "profile-rustflags" https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10271, which allows setting rustflags based on profile. rustflags can include `--cfg feature="foo"`, so it seems that this will allow indirectly setting features based on the profile.

Is my understanding correct?